# Trying to set a dynamic variable as the result of a sql statement

Tags: sql, dynamic

I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

on the line

```
set @a = 'select year
```

This is my code:

```
declare @a uniqueidentifier
set @a = 'select year
          from rev.rev_year
          where class_year = ''2014'''
```

`year` is a uniqueidentifier so I thought to make `@a` one as well in order for it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Right now, you're setting your variable `@a` to be that whole SQL statement - which of course isn't a `uniqueidentifier`, but really just a long string .... why do you need to do this using *dynamic* SQL ?

Comment: @marc_s So how could I go about setting `@a` to equal `year` which is a uniqueidentifier? How else would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear why you feel the need for *dynamic* SQL here ....

Just try:

```
DECLARE @a uniqueidentifier

SELECT @a = tbl.year
FROM rev.rev_year tbl
WHERE tbl.class_year = '2014'
```

and you're done.

Comment: The column `year` from that table `rev.rev_year` which I decorated with a `tbl` alias to make things clearer. The trouble is that `year` is a reserved SQL Server keyword and thus a poor choice for a column name (especially since a `year` would typically be expected to be a numerical value - 2014 for instance - but not a `uniqueidentifier`)

Comment: I didn't notice the `tbl` on the `From` line until after the post